# Professor Elm is always asking about Togepi, how can I skip that?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

Prof Elm at the start of the game gave me an egg and it hatched as a Togepi, but I traded it to a friend time ago and now the professor is always asking about it.

Is there any way to skip that conversation via PokéGear? Am I missing something without telling him about the Togepi?

Comment: Man, he really wanted that Togepi !

Comment: Does showing a different Togepi help? If you breed one yourself, I don't think there is any way for the professor to tell the difference.

Comment: I don't remember that part well... but I showed it to him when it hatched. From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960099-pokemon-heartgold-version/54190954), it *looks* like you could stop it if you showed him the Togepi (third post).

Comment: I'll try to show him a new Togepi then

Answer (score 3):

I finally found out how to do it, even though I hadn't the same Togepi or Egg the professor gave me in Heart Gold, I had a Togekiss who was a Togetic that I transfered from Fire Red to this version, and the professor Elm still accepted it as the Pokémon he wanted to see, so it's not about only the Togepi or the Original Trainer (OT) but the evolutionary line of its own.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Professor_Elm#In_the_games):

> After successfully hatching the Egg containing Togepi, he gives the player an Everstone

so you don't miss anything important.

I'm pretty sure that he will stop nagging you if you show him another Togepi (an evolution should work, too).

Answer (score 0):

Usually the only way that you can get him to shut up is by showing him the Togepi.. or a Togepi.. it doesn't have to be the one you hatched.

However you are not missing anything too crucial to the storyline if you don't have the Togepi anymore so don't worry about it.